Is there a way to solve my problem about uncomplye6 Unknown magic number 8224?
I disassemble this pyobfuscated script by manually changing this into this
and run the script like (python3 thtt.py > thtt.pyc) and I got [this results] (https://github.com/vampiremoe/ua/blob/main/thtt.pyc)
Now the real problem started, I want to convert that thtt.pyc into humanized format like (import os,sys,...etc)
so I did (uncompyle6 -o . /root/Downloads/thtt.pyc )
and it shows (Unknow magic number 8224)
I also used pyc-xasm and the other methods, even the copilot give up in that case.How should I do to get readable script? Reverse engineering the obfuscated thtt.py script? if yes how? The tool that pyobfuscated thtt.py script is here
If you wonder why I want to do such a thing , I don't have enough knowledge in programming and that script I provide above was stoled my data through telegram bot to his chat id. So that I want him to admit what he have done to me by showing evidence of the real script. Thanks, If you need more info I will provide you and I humbly request you all.

I read "uncompyle6 translates Python bytecode back into equivalent Python source code." What you have got as shown in thtt.pyc is disassembly output, it's not bytecode.

thanks for the reply, finally I gave up that and start learning basic stuff for own development ♥️

If you still want to try a thing: instead of dis.dis, marshal.dump(_(b'…'), "thtt.pyc")
